# Can I have Two Wordpress Logo In My website - One For Responsive And Other For Non-Responsive design?

Tags: css, wordpress, graphical-logo

My Theme Was Supposed To Be responsive But when I uploaded Logo In My Site, It stop Being Responsive. So can i have one logo(big) for non-responsive design and other (small) for responsive design.

Comment: What do you mean that it 'stopped being responsive'? The whole site, or did you expect the logo to scale down as well? If you apply `width:100%;height:auto` to the img it will scale down.

Answer (score 0):

When would you want it to be responsive and when would you want it to not be responsive? Most of what you sound like you want to achieve could be done through media queries.

```
.logo{
background-image: url(images/image_nonresponsive.jpg);
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
.logo{
background-image: url(images/image_responsive.jpg);
}
```

This will enable your responsive logo at 320px width.

Answer (score 0):

There is another method:

**HTML**

```
<img src="logo_mobile.jpg" class="visible-mobile" />
<img src="logo_desktop.jpg" class="hidden-mobile" />
```

**CSS**

```
.visible-mobile{ display: none; }
.hidden-mobile{ display: inherit; }

@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .visible-mobile{ display: inherit; }
    .hidden-mobile{ display: none;  }
}
```

This will show or hide your logo depending from your screen size.
You can see an **example** here: http://cdpn.io/wyqxz

The difference is that in this case both images will be loaded from your browser so is not the best solution for your site performances.

Comment: Here is another solution that allows you to use only one logo: http://jsfiddle.net/B54Ur/